# PHP querying MySQL, showing "count(*)"

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have inherited an old system at work, php 4.4 and MySQL that we run our helpdesk software from, I cannot upgrade anything until next year.
I'm struggling with something though.
I need to show the total number of calls logged between 2 and 1 hour ago. in the database, the unix timestamp for each call logged is in the column "logdatex"
in my php I have the following

```
$OneHourAgo = strtotime('-1 hour'); //time 1 hour ago as Unix Timestamp
$TwoHoursAgo = strtotime('-400 hour'); // time 2 hours ago

$Test = mysql_query("select count(*) from opencall where logdatex between $OneHourAgo and $TwoHoursAgo") or die(mysql_error());
```

Now, in MySQL Query Browser, if I put in the query but replace the variables with the actual numbers (I did an echo to get the numbers) it works fine and returns the desired number:

> select count(*) from opencall where logdatex between 1326767703 and
>   1386764103

(the above doesn't use a 1 hour sample, more like a few years) Please can you help me get the number in to a variable, I cannot figure out how to do this.
Any help appreciated

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Do you get an error?

Answer (score 2):

The `mysql_query` does not directly return the results of the query.  Rather it returns a result resource. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

So you will need to use `mysql_fetch_row` to get the results.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($Test);
$count = $row[0];
```

If you have more than one row, you would loop until the mysql_fetch_row returns false.  But since you know you are only going to get one row, you can do this.

Comment: Thank you! this and the addition from Ramesh has got it working!

Answer (score 1):

You should change your query:

```
select count(*) from opencall where logdatex between $TwoHoursAgo and $OneHourAgo
```

Because http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between says, it should be between min and max.

Comment: Thank you! this and the addition from Schleis has got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand you but, may be that?

```
$OneHourAgo = strtotime('-1 hour'); //time 1 hour ago as Unix Timestamp
$TwoHoursAgo = strtotime('-2 hour'); // time 2 hours ago
```

A link: http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php